# System.UnauthorizedAccessException (A first chance exception)

Tags: c#, exception

I am getting the

> *A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll*

exception from this bit of code:

```
string[] filesList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\", "*.exe",
                                         SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

What its doing is listing all files with an .exe extention, although for certain directories it works, but some it throws this.

Any ideas on what I can do to resolve it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "first chance exception" occurs before the exception handler is invoked. If you don't want VS to stop on these, uncheck the boxes in Debug > Exceptions. Note that running the debugger as administrator, as some have suggested, will change its behavior ... you should test your program with and without elevated privilege.

Comment: Thank you, elevated privileges worked! Along with security permission in the meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run your app as admin.

Here's he right way to do it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhiln/archive/2007/04/19/embed-a-manifest-to-make-an-application-elevate-in-vista.aspx

Comment: Except that what do you do when there's no .exe file, just .dlls?

Comment: @HotLicks, I'm not sure how you can execute code in a dll without going thru an exe. Even if you do it indirectly via things like rundll32, or powershell, those are both .exe's that can be run as admin. If you know there's an .exe, but you don't have control over it, then you can always spawn your own .exe, and it'll ask for elevation (and return the results to the parent .exe).

Answer (score 3):

On some versions of windows, the program files directories are pretty well locked down. This prevents errant users from damaging the parts of the file system essential for correct OS running. If you run your debugger (and application) with elevated privileges then it will pass.

Comment: How can I run the dubugger with elevated privileges? I am using VS 2012.

Comment: Restart dev studio; choosing "Run As Administrator"; you can do this on a right click.

Answer (score 3):

If you using Vista, **Program Files** folder is protected by operating system by [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control).

> Applications written with the assumption that the user will be running
>   with administrator privileges experienced problems in earlier versions
>   of Windows when run from limited user accounts, often because they
>   attempted to write to machine-wide or system directories (such as
>   Program Files) or registry keys. **UAC attempts to alleviate this
>   using File and Registry Virtualization, which redirects writes (and
>   subsequent reads) to a per-user location within the user’s profile.**
>   For example, if an application attempts to write to **“C:\program
>   files\appname\settings.ini”** and the user doesn’t have permissions to
>   write to that directory, the write will get redirected to
>   **“C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\appname\settings.ini”**

And be aware, Program Files is *special folder*. If you want to get its path, you can use [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration. Like;

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
```